# How can I format a thrift file in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, thrift

No thrift formatters extensions found in vscode extensions.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can install [thrift extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cduruk.thrift&ssr=false#overview) to support `*.thrift` files in VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this extension [Thrift Formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alingse.thirft-formatter) too, It's source code: [thrift-fmt-vscode](https://github.com/thrift-labs/thrift-fmt-vscode)

(and there is still many feature to implement

and a commandline tool  version [thrift-fmt](https://github.com/thrift-labs/thrift-fmt)